# Java generic lambda call

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I got a class, that has a Interface Object in the constructor:

```
private Operator(/* ..., */ final Operation<?> operation) {
    //...
}
```

Operation is a generic interface with one method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T applyOperation(T... arguments);
```

I can now create an Object of class Operator like this:

```
public static final Operator POSTFIX_INCREASE = new Operator(/* ...,*/ new Operation<Integer>() {

    @Override
    public Integer applyOperation(Integer... arguments) {
        return arguments[0]++;
    }
});
```

But I'd like to this with a lambda expression. This is what eclipse itself reconmends (And it looks good so far):

```
public static final Operator POSTFIX_INCREASE = new Operator("++", 0, 1, true, arguments -> arguments[0]++);
```

The only problem... It does not work :D Of course I know, i need to provide type information: I need an integer implementation of the Operator interface. In the anonymous class I can just provide it the default way, but in a lambda expression, this isn't possible. Is there any way to write a generic lambda expression, or don't they support that?
(what wouldn't be a big surprise, since generics aren't very flexible in java)

Comment: Provide an explicit type for `arguments`

Comment: How do you mean this? The variable arguments in the interface shall be generic. Or do you mean the call of arguments in the lambda expression? Because then I want to know how to provide arguments explicit

Comment: Java doesn't know what the type of `arguments` is meant to be. It can't infer it from anywhere. Use `(Integer... arguments) -> ...` for example.

Comment: A great, that was exactly what I was searching for :D I knew that I need to provide the type explicit, but I didn't know, that I can do this on the argument inside the lambda directly. Can you post this as an answer, so I can mark this as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your parameter type is using a wildcard

```
final Operation<?> operation
```

and the instance creation expression has no additional type information

```
public static final Operator POSTFIX_INCREASE = new Operator("++", 0, 1, true, arguments -> arguments[0]++);
```

the compiler has no way to decide what type infer for your lambda expression's parameter.

You need to be explicit here. Either change your constructor parameter type

```
private Sample(/* ..., */ final Operation<Integer> operation) {
```

or specify the lambda parameter type

```
new Operator("++", 0, 1, true, (Integer... arguments) -> arguments[0]++)
```